# Replace empty cells with zeros after a filter

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to replace empty cells with zeros in a different column to the one for which the a `filter` using `dplyr` is applied. For example,

```
temp %>% 
  filter(Publication.type == "Link") %>% 
  # ** Insert function or 2 to replace NAs by zeroes in another column, 
     say Clicks_30min  **
```

I believe the `is.na` function doesn't work here, nor does replace. Open to alternative solutions as well. Would mutate_at work? I tried mutate and it threw an error.

Comment: Why does `replace` or `mutate(...)` not work? Could you show that you tried it and the error msg you receive?

Comment: I've added the error thrown in a comment in the answer below, there's a lot of data in other columns and they are of different data types.

Answer (score 3):

We can do

```
temp %>% 
   filter(Publication.type == "Link") %>%
   mutate_all(funs(replace(., .=="", 0)))
```

If the empty cells are `NA`, then

```
temp %>% 
   filter(Publication.type == "Link") %>%
   mutate_all(funs(replace(., is.na(.), 0)))
```

Comment: Hi, tried this, but it tells me there's an error:                                   
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
Evaluation error: 'origin' must be supplied.
In addition: Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, list, value = 0) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated

Comment: Edited the question statement a bit for clarity

Comment: @PrathameshHoshing Looks like you have `factor` columns, try `mutate_all(funs(replace(as.character(.), is.na(.), "0")))`